# Can I change my appearance later in the game?

Tags: destiny

I'm setting my appearance before I even know what's going on. Will I have an option to change my gender/physical features later?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I've seen nothing to indicate an appearance change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is currently nothing in the game to allow you to change your features after character creation.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is put all your gear which has light in the vault, delete your old character, make a new one with whatever changes you want, get that character to level 20 (which isn't that hard) and than get all of your light gear out of the vault, that way your the same level as you were with desired appearance